# Eclipse/PyDev raises a java.io.IOException: Invalid Argument

Tags: java, python, eclipse, pydev

Every time I attempt to use the PyDev function, Attach debugger to running python process, I get the next exception:

**Java.io.IOException: Invalid argument**

I went to check eclipse's log and I found the next trace entries,

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid argument

at java.io.FileInputStream.available(Native Method)
        at org.python.pydev.shared_core.io.FileUtils.fillBufferWithStream(FileUtils.java:348)
        at org.python.pydev.shared_core.io.FileUtils.fillBufferWithStream(FileUtils.java:319)
        at org.python.pydev.shared_core.io.FileUtils.getStreamContents(FileUtils.java:552)
        at org.python.pydev.shared_core.io.FileUtils.getFileContentsCustom(FileUtils.java:602)

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems there's only a tiny part of the stack trace there, so, it's not possible to reason about it...